# Как взять все числа от какого-то и до какого-то числа sqlite3

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Работаю с sqlite3 и нужно из базы взять все элементы со значениями от 3 до 1000. Как это сделать через запрос?

Comment: Ну, просто `WHERE значение BETWEEN 3 AND 1000` наверное? Да и даже если вы не в курсе про BETWEEN, то хотя бы догадаться написать `WHERE значение >= 3 AND значение <= 1000` вполне можно было

Comment: да уж, в конкурсе невнятных и неоднозначных вопросов данный вопрос вполне может претендовать на одно из призовых мест.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы последовательно получить все числа от 3 до 1000 (включительно), можно воспользоваться следующим [рекурсивным запросом](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_query_examples):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (
     SELECT 3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT x+1 FROM cnt
      LIMIT 998
  )
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```

Вывод:

```
x
---
3
4
5
6
...
998
999
1000
```

Но если вы просто хотите получить данные из таблицы по диапазону чисел, то разумнее воспользоваться оператором [`WHERE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#whereclause).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT value FROM (table) WHERE value > 3 AND value < 1000
```

Comment: За что вам минус непонятно. Ловите компенсационный плюс